# Reflecting over all properties of an interface, including inherited ones?

Tags: c#, reflection

I have an instance of System.Type that represents an interface, and I want to get a list of all the properties on that interface -- including those inherited from base interfaces. I basically want the same behavior from interfaces that I get for classes.

For example, given this hierarchy:

```
public interface IBase {
    public string BaseProperty { get; }
}
public interface ISub : IBase {
    public string SubProperty { get; }
}
public class Base : IBase {
    public string BaseProperty { get { return "Base"; } }
}
public class Sub : Base, ISub {
    public string SubProperty { get { return "Sub"; } }
}
```

If I call GetProperties on the class -- `typeof(Sub).GetProperties()` -- then I get both BaseProperty and SubProperty. I want to do the same thing with the interface, but when I try it -- `typeof(ISub).GetProperties()` -- all that comes back is SubProperty.

I tried passing `BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy` to GetProperties, since my understanding of FlattenHierarchy is that it's supposed to include members from base classes, but the behavior was exactly the same.

I suppose I could iterate `Type.GetInterfaces()` and call GetProperties on each one, but then I would be relying on GetProperties on an interface to *never* return base properties (since if it ever did, I'd get duplicates). I'd rather not rely on this behavior without at least seeing it documented.

How can I either:

- Get a list of all the properties on an interface, including those from its base interfaces? Or
- At least be confident that what I'm seeing is documented behavior that I can rely on, so I can work around it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [GetProperties() to return all properties for an interface inheritance hierarchy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/358835/getproperties-to-return-all-properties-for-an-interface-inheritance-hierarchy)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An answer of sorts is to be found in an *annotation* to [the .NET framework version 3.5-specific MSDN page on `GetProperties(BindingFlags bindingFlags)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyaxdd3x%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) :

> Passing BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy
>   to one of the Type.GetXXX methods,
>   such as Type.GetMembers, will not
>   return inherited interface members
>   when you are querying on an interface
>   type itself.
>
> [...]
>
> To get the inherited members, you need
>   to query each implemented interface
>   for its members.

Example code is also included. This comment was posted by a Microsoftie, so I would say you can trust it.

Comment: The "community addition" you mention is not shown for the current version of that page - you have to go back to the .Net Framework 3.5 version. Here's a direct link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyaxdd3x%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

See here: [GetProperties() to return all properties for an interface inheritance hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/358835/getproperties-to-return-all-properties-for-an-interface-inheritance-hierarchy)

I don't think it's possible to get all members without doing what you suggested (i.e. getting all the implementing interfaces.)