# GetProperties for inherited/child class with appropriate BindingFlags does not return expected properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I did follow the following posts' suggestions

1. [Reflecting over all properties of an interface, including inherited ones?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132791/reflecting-over-all-properties-of-an-interface-including-inherited-ones)
2. [How do you get the all properties of a class and its base classes (up the hierarchy) with Reflection? (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245055/how-do-you-get-the-all-properties-of-a-class-and-its-base-classes-up-the-hierar)
3. [Using GetProperties() with BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly in .NET Reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544979/using-getproperties-with-bindingflags-declaredonly-in-net-reflection)

and modified my test to include the bindingflags as seen below.

**Goal**:
 my end goal is to test if the retrieved property is `readOnly`.

**Issue**:
 ChildClass/Inherited class property does not even show up on reflection.

Test to check if property `exists` - `fails`.

On `GetProperties(BindingFlags.FlattenHiearchy)` returns only one property which  is the `Result` which is the parent class's property

```
//My failing test
Assert.NotNull(typeof(ChildClass).GetProperty("Id",BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly));

//My Alternate version which still fails
Assert.NotNull(typeof(ChildClass).GetProperty("Id",BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy));

// My class structure against which my test is running.
class ChildClass:BaseClass<MyCustomObject>
{
   public ChildClass (Guid id)
    {
        Id = id;
    }

    public readonly Guid Id;
}

class BaseClass<T>:IMyInterFace<T>
{
     public T Result { get; private set; }
}

public interface IMyInterFace<T>
{
    T Result { get; }

}
```

**EDIT** 9/14/2016
I apologize I missed the fact that I actually did know or understand I can `Assert.NotNull` if i say `GetField` - but that wouldnt help me achieve the end goal - to check if it is `readonly` - I am now unsure as to if this is even possible can someone confirm? thanks!.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`public readonly Guid Id` is a *field*, not a property. Use the `GetField` method instead:

```
typeof(ChildClass).GetField("Id", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
```

You can check to see if it is `readonly` by looking at the `IsInitOnly` property of the `FieldInfo` class.

```
var result = typeof(ChildClass).GetField("Id", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
Assert.IsTrue(result.IsInitOnly);
```

Comment: Sure, this would work, but how would I achieve my end there that is stated - meaning I would want to check if it is read only - is that not possible given that it is a field?

Comment: @JS_GodBlessAll In the second part of my answer I stated that you can check by looking at the `IsInitOnly` property from result. Did that work for you?

Comment: ... As in `var result = typeof(ChildClass).GetField(/*all that stuff*/)` then `Assert.IsTrue(result.IsInitOnly)`