# Resolving a member name at runtime

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, reflection, c#-5.0, overload-resolution

Given a *type*, a *name* and a *signature*, how can I do a member lookup of the member with name *name* and signature *signature* using the C# rules of 7.4 (the 7.4 is the chapter number from the C# Language Specification) (or at least part of them... Let's say I can live with an exact match, without conversions/casts) **at runtime**? I need to get a `MethodInfo`/`PropertyInfo`/... because then I have to use it with reflection (to be more exact I'm trying to build an `Expression.ForEach` builder (a factory able to create an Expression Tree that represent a `foreach` statement), and to be pixel-perfect with the C# `foreach` I have to be able to do duck-typing and search for a `GetEnumerator` method (in the collection), a `Current` property and a `MoveNext` method (in the enumerator), as written in 8.8.4)

The problem (an example of the problem)

```
class C1
{
    public int Current { get; set; }

    public object MoveNext()
    {
        return null;
    }
}

class C2 : C1
{
    public new long Current { get; set; }

    public new bool MoveNext()
    {
        return true;
    }
}

class C3 : C2
{
}

var m = typeof(C3).GetMethods(); // I get both versions of MoveNext()
var p = typeof(C3).GetProperties(); // I get both versions of Current
```

Clearly if I try `typeof(C3).GetProperty("Current")` I get an `AmbiguousMatchException` exception.

A similar but different problem is present with interfaces:

```
interface I0
{
    int Current { get; set; }
}

interface I1 : I0
{
    new long Current { get; set; }
}

interface I2 : I1, I0
{
    new object Current { get; set; }
}

interface I3 : I2
{
}
```

Here if I try to do a `typeof(I3).GetProperties()` I don't get the `Current` property (and this is something known, see for example [GetProperties() to return all properties for an interface inheritance hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/358835/getproperties-to-return-all-properties-for-an-interface-inheritance-hierarchy)), but I can't simply flatten the interfaces, because then I wouldn't know who is hiding who.

I know that probably this problem is solved somewhere in the `Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder` namespace (declared in the `Microsoft.CSharp` assembly). This because I'm trying to use C# rules and member lookup is necessary when you have dynamic method invocation, but I haven't been able to find anything (and then what I would get would be an `Expression` or perhaps a direct invocation).

After some thought it's clear that there is something similar in the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` assembly. VB.NET supports late binding. It's in `Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.NewLateBinding`, but it doesn't expose the late bounded methods.

Comment: I looked into using `Binder` for this as you suggested, but didn't figure out how to do it. You can bind to the correct property for the runtime type, but not for some other type it inherits (like `I3`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(note: shadowing = hiding = new in method/property/event definition in C#)

No one responded, so I'll post the code I cooked in the meantime. I hate to post 400 lines of code, but I wanted to be complete. There are two main methods: `GetVisibleMethods` and `GetVisibleProperties`. They are extension methods of the `Type` class. They will return the *public visible* (non-shadowed/non-overridden) methods/properties of a type. They should even handle VB.NET assemblies (VB.NET normally uses `hide-by-name` shadowing instead of `hidebysig` as done by C#). They cache their result in two static collections (`Methods` and `Properties`). The code is for C# 4.0, so I'm using `ConcurrentDictionary<T, U>`. If you are using C# 3.5 you can replace it with a `Dictionary<T, U>` but you have to protect it with a `lock` () { } when you read from it and when you write to it.

How does it works? It works by recursion (I know that recursion is normally bad, but I hope no one will create a 1.000 level inheritance chain).

For "real" types (non-interfaces) it walks upward one level (using recursion, so this one level up could go one level up and so on) and, from the returned list of methods/properties, it removes the methods/properties it's overloading/hiding.

For interfaces it's a little more complex. `Type.GetInterfaces()` returns all the interfaces that are inherited, ignoring if they are directly inherited or indirectly inherited. For each of those interfaces a list of declared methods/properties is calculated (through recursion). This list is paired with a list of methods/properties that are hidden by the interface (the `HashSet<MethodInfo>`/`HashSet<PropertyInfo>`). These methods/properties hidden by one interface or another are removed from all the other methods/properties returned from interfaces (so that if you have `I1` with `Method1(int)`, `I2` inheriting from `I1` that redeclares `Method1(int)` and in doing so hides `I1.Method1` and `I3` inheriting from `I1` and `I2`, the fact that `I2` hides `I1.Method1` will be applied to the methods returned from exploring `I1`, so removing `I1.Method1(int)` (this happens because I don't generate an inheritance map for interfaces, I simply look at what hides what)).

From the returned collections of methods/properties one can use Linq to find the looked for method/property. Note that with interfaces you could find more than one method/property with a given signature. An example:

```
interface I1
{
    void Method1();
}

interface I2
{
    void Method1();
}

interface I3 : I1, I2
{
}
```

`I3` will return two `Method1()`.

The code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

public static class TypeEx
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Type, Tuple&lt;Methods of type, (for interfaces)methods of base interfaces shadowed&gt;
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Type, Tuple<MethodInfo[], HashSet<MethodInfo>>> Methods = new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, Tuple<MethodInfo[], HashSet<MethodInfo>>>();

    /// <summary>
    /// Type, Tuple&lt;Properties of type, (for interfaces)properties of base interfaces shadowed&gt;
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Type, Tuple<PropertyInfo[], HashSet<PropertyInfo>>> Properties = new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, Tuple<PropertyInfo[], HashSet<PropertyInfo>>>();

    public static MethodInfo[] GetVisibleMethods(this Type type)
    {
        if (type.IsInterface)
        {
            return (MethodInfo[])type.GetVisibleMethodsInterfaceImpl().Item1.Clone();
        }

        return (MethodInfo[])type.GetVisibleMethodsImpl().Clone();
    }

    public static PropertyInfo[] GetVisibleProperties(this Type type)
    {
        if (type.IsInterface)
        {
            return (PropertyInfo[])type.GetVisiblePropertiesInterfaceImpl().Item1.Clone();
        }

        return (PropertyInfo[])type.GetVisiblePropertiesImpl().Clone();
    }

    private static MethodInfo[] GetVisibleMethodsImpl(this Type type)
    {
        Tuple<MethodInfo[], HashSet<MethodInfo>> tuple;

        if (Methods.TryGetValue(type, out tuple))
        {
            return tuple.Item1;
        }

        var methods = type.GetMethods(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);

        if (type.BaseType == null)
        {
            Methods.TryAdd(type, Tuple.Create(methods, (HashSet<MethodInfo>)null));
            return methods;
        }

        var baseMethods = type.BaseType.GetVisibleMethodsImpl().ToList();

        foreach (var method in methods)
        {
            if (method.IsHideByName())
            {
                baseMethods.RemoveAll(p => p.Name == method.Name);
            }
            else
            {
                int numGenericArguments = method.GetGenericArguments().Length;
                var parameters = method.GetParameters();

                baseMethods.RemoveAll(p =>
                {
                    if (!method.EqualSignature(numGenericArguments, parameters, p))
                    {
                        return false;
                    }

                    return true;
                });
            }
        }

        if (baseMethods.Count == 0)
        {
            Methods.TryAdd(type, Tuple.Create(methods, (HashSet<MethodInfo>)null));
            return methods;
        }

        var methods3 = new MethodInfo[methods.Length + baseMethods.Count];

        Array.Copy(methods, 0, methods3, 0, methods.Length);
        baseMethods.CopyTo(methods3, methods.Length);

        Methods.TryAdd(type, Tuple.Create(methods3, (HashSet<MethodInfo>)null));
        return methods3;
    }

    private static Tuple<MethodInfo[], HashSet<MethodInfo>> GetVisibleMethodsInterfaceImpl(this Type type)
    {
        Tuple<MethodInfo[], HashSet<MethodInfo>> tuple;

        if (Methods.TryGetValue(type, out tuple))
        {
            return tuple;
        }

        var methods = type.GetMethods(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);

        var baseInterfaces = type.GetInterfaces();

        if (baseInterfaces.Length == 0)
        {
            tuple = Tuple.Create(methods, new HashSet<MethodInfo>());
            Methods.TryAdd(type, tuple);
            return tuple;
        }

        var baseMethods = new List<MethodInfo>();

        var baseMethodsTemp = new MethodInfo[baseInterfaces.Length][];

        var shadowedMethods = new HashSet<MethodInfo>();

        for (int i = 0; i < baseInterfaces.Length; i++)
        {
            var tuple2 = baseInterfaces[i].GetVisibleMethodsInterfaceImpl();
            baseMethodsTemp[i] = tuple2.Item1;
            shadowedMethods.UnionWith(tuple2.Item2);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < baseInterfaces.Length; i++)
        {
            baseMethods.AddRange(baseMethodsTemp[i].Where(p => !shadowedMethods.Contains(p)));
        }

        foreach (var method in methods)
        {
            if (method.IsHideByName())
            {
                baseMethods.RemoveAll(p =>
                {
                    if (p.Name == method.Name)
                    {
                        shadowedMethods.Add(p);
                        return true;
                    }

                    return false;
                });
            }
            else
            {
                int numGenericArguments = method.GetGenericArguments().Length;
                var parameters = method.GetParameters();

                baseMethods.RemoveAll(p =>
                {
                    if (!method.EqualSignature(numGenericArguments, parameters, p))
                    {
                        return false;
                    }

                    shadowedMethods.Add(p);
                    return true;
                });
            }
        }

        if (baseMethods.Count == 0)
        {
            tuple = Tuple.Create(methods, shadowedMethods);
            Methods.TryAdd(type, tuple);
            return tuple;
        }

        var methods3 = new MethodInfo[methods.Length + baseMethods.Count];

        Array.Copy(methods, 0, methods3, 0, methods.Length);
        baseMethods.CopyTo(methods3, methods.Length);

        tuple = Tuple.Create(methods3, shadowedMethods);
        Methods.TryAdd(type, tuple);
        return tuple;
    }

    private static PropertyInfo[] GetVisiblePropertiesImpl(this Type type)
    {
        Tuple<PropertyInfo[], HashSet<PropertyInfo>> tuple;

        if (Properties.TryGetValue(type, out tuple))
        {
            return tuple.Item1;
        }

        var properties = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);

        if (type.BaseType == null)
        {
            Properties.TryAdd(type, Tuple.Create(properties, (HashSet<PropertyInfo>)null));
            return properties;
        }

        var baseProperties = type.BaseType.GetVisiblePropertiesImpl().ToList();

        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            if (property.IsHideByName())
            {
                baseProperties.RemoveAll(p => p.Name == property.Name);
            }
            else
            {
                var indexers = property.GetIndexParameters();

                baseProperties.RemoveAll(p =>
                {
                    if (!property.EqualSignature(indexers, p))
                    {
                        return false;
                    }

                    return true;
                });
            }
        }

        if (baseProperties.Count == 0)
        {
            Properties.TryAdd(type, Tuple.Create(properties, (HashSet<PropertyInfo>)null));
            return properties;
        }

        var properties3 = new PropertyInfo[properties.Length + baseProperties.Count];

        Array.Copy(properties, 0, properties3, 0, properties.Length);
        baseProperties.CopyTo(properties3, properties.Length);

        Properties.TryAdd(type, Tuple.Create(properties3, (HashSet<PropertyInfo>)null));
        return properties3;
    }

    private static Tuple<PropertyInfo[], HashSet<PropertyInfo>> GetVisiblePropertiesInterfaceImpl(this Type type)
    {
        Tuple<PropertyInfo[], HashSet<PropertyInfo>> tuple;

        if (Properties.TryGetValue(type, out tuple))
        {
            return tuple;
        }

        var properties = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);

        var baseInterfaces = type.GetInterfaces();

        if (baseInterfaces.Length == 0)
        {
            tuple = Tuple.Create(properties, new HashSet<PropertyInfo>());
            Properties.TryAdd(type, tuple);
            return tuple;
        }

        var baseProperties = new List<PropertyInfo>();

        var basePropertiesTemp = new PropertyInfo[baseInterfaces.Length][];

        var shadowedProperties = new HashSet<PropertyInfo>();

        for (int i = 0; i < baseInterfaces.Length; i++)
        {
            var tuple2 = baseInterfaces[i].GetVisiblePropertiesInterfaceImpl();
            basePropertiesTemp[i] = tuple2.Item1;
            shadowedProperties.UnionWith(tuple2.Item2);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < baseInterfaces.Length; i++)
        {
            baseProperties.AddRange(basePropertiesTemp[i].Where(p => !shadowedProperties.Contains(p)));
        }

        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            if (property.IsHideByName())
            {
                baseProperties.RemoveAll(p =>
                {
                    if (p.Name == property.Name)
                    {
                        shadowedProperties.Add(p);
                        return true;
                    }

                    return false;
                });
            }
            else
            {
                var indexers = property.GetIndexParameters();

                baseProperties.RemoveAll(p =>
                {
                    if (!property.EqualSignature(indexers, p))
                    {
                        return false;
                    }

                    shadowedProperties.Add(p);
                    return true;
                });
            }
        }

        if (baseProperties.Count == 0)
        {
            tuple = Tuple.Create(properties, shadowedProperties);
            Properties.TryAdd(type, tuple);
            return tuple;
        }

        var properties3 = new PropertyInfo[properties.Length + baseProperties.Count];

        Array.Copy(properties, 0, properties3, 0, properties.Length);
        baseProperties.CopyTo(properties3, properties.Length);

        tuple = Tuple.Create(properties3, shadowedProperties);
        Properties.TryAdd(type, tuple);
        return tuple;
    }

    private static bool EqualSignature(this MethodInfo method1, int numGenericArguments1, ParameterInfo[] parameters1, MethodInfo method2)
    {
        // To shadow by signature a method must have same name, same number of 
        // generic arguments, same number of parameters and same parameters' type
        if (method1.Name != method2.Name)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (numGenericArguments1 != method2.GetGenericArguments().Length)
        {
            return false;
        }

        var parameters2 = method2.GetParameters();

        if (!parameters1.EqualParameterTypes(parameters2))
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    private static bool EqualSignature(this PropertyInfo property1, ParameterInfo[] indexers1, PropertyInfo property2)
    {
        // To shadow by signature a property must have same name, 
        // same number of indexers and same indexers' type
        if (property1.Name != property2.Name)
        {
            return false;
        }

        var parameters2 = property1.GetIndexParameters();

        if (!indexers1.EqualParameterTypes(parameters2))
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    private static bool EqualParameterTypes(this ParameterInfo[] parameters1, ParameterInfo[] parameters2)
    {
        if (parameters1.Length != parameters2.Length)
        {
            return false;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < parameters1.Length; i++)
        {
            if (parameters1[i].IsOut != parameters2[i].IsOut)
            {
                return false;
            }

            if (parameters1[i].ParameterType.IsGenericParameter)
            {
                if (!parameters2[i].ParameterType.IsGenericParameter)
                {
                    return false;
                }

                if (parameters1[i].ParameterType.GenericParameterPosition != parameters2[i].ParameterType.GenericParameterPosition)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else if (parameters1[i].ParameterType != parameters2[i].ParameterType)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    private static bool IsHideByName(this MethodInfo method)
    {
        if (!method.Attributes.HasFlag(MethodAttributes.HideBySig) && (!method.Attributes.HasFlag(MethodAttributes.Virtual) || method.Attributes.HasFlag(MethodAttributes.NewSlot)))
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    private static bool IsHideByName(this PropertyInfo property)
    {
        var get = property.GetGetMethod();

        if (get != null && get.IsHideByName())
        {
            return true;
        }

        var set = property.GetSetMethod();

        if (set != null && set.IsHideByName())
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Recursion is not “normally bad”. Yes, it can blow your stack, but that doesn't means you shouldn't use it, just that you have to be careful in some cases.

Comment: Whew, this saved me a TON of time. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use overloaded method with `BindingFlags` parameter.

```
GetProperties(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly)
```

Comment: Beep! Wrong answer :-) This is the reason there is an empty `C3`. `Current` is part of `C2`.